# how to join sys_query_history and stl_querytext in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I need Some Info for Executed query from sys_query_history
like
status,result_cache_hit,start time,end_time,erroor message

and get the full text from stl_querytext

How to join these 2 table Since the queryid is different in these 2 table

i was using sys_query_history.transaction_id= stl_querytext.xid
and sys_query_history.session_id= stl_querytext.pid

but its not working since user can execute more than 1 quert in same session
in that case the query_id in  sys_query_history is not same as query in stl_querytext

Answer (score 3):

SYS system views are new logging methods. You can't join STL and SYS tables views. Redshift logs data differently (with diff queryid) in SYS views compared to STL tables. STL and SYS tables can't be used in combination.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "the queryid is different in these 2 table".  Both sys_query_history and stl_querytext have the query id as a column (query_id and query respectively).

You should just add -

```
AND sys_query_history.query_id= stl_querytext.query
```

to your JOIN ON clause.

Comment: The Value are not same in both the table for query_id & query column. So how they can be joined on sys_query_history.query_id= stl_querytext.query

Comment: Not the same in what way?  Don't have the same value or formatted differently?  Xid, Pid, and query_id values are all recycled and are not unique over a period of time.  Also system tables are only kept for a few days on Redshift.  Check the timestamps of the rows you are joining as getting things cross-wired is possible. If you still need help aligning look at stl_query (source table not view) as it has partial query text and can help bridge these other 2 system objects.

Comment: My Requirement is to join sys_query_history & stl_query if we do it based on sys_query_history.query_id= stl_querytext.query i am not getting any row since the query_id & query are not matching.  They dont have same value.

Comment: How old is the query? Redshift doesn't keep system tables around very long.  Can you see the partial query text in sys_query_history?  When you join by XID are you seeing the expected 4000 characters of the desired query or are the queries not the same?  What about timestamps matching?  Also, is there a match in stl_query?

Comment: I've actually found this issue as well. I'm able to track a query id via the console and it's not in this table.